# How to match a group of value to group 1

Tags: regex, pcre

Was tying to solve a regex question posted in SO, but was stuck with this.

From this string

```
Ob=Web technology,OB=Product SPe,OB=Dev profile,OB=Computer Management,oB=Hardware Services,cd=sti,CD=com,cd=ws
```

The values has to be removed as below.

```
Web technology,Product SPe,Dev profile,Computer Management,Hardware Services
```

I was trying the below regex.

```
(?=Ob)(?:(\w+=)([\w\s]+,?))+
```

My assumption was that `group 1` should have all keys and `group 2` should have all the values. But all except the last key value pair all others are getting assigned to `group 0`.

Is there a way go getting all values to `group 2` ?

And [here is what I was working on](http://regex101.com/r/mN8jJ8/1).

Comment: @Yal What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your regex is that `group 1` and `group 2` are enclosed within a non-capturing group. This caused the entire regex to get captured with `group 0`. And the other thing is the the positive-lookahead prevented the regex to do a global match.

Below regex will gather all `keys` to group to `group 1` and `values` to `group 2`.

```
(\w+)=([\w\s]+)(?=[,\s]+)
```

Check it out how it [works here](http://regex101.com/r/eO5vQ0/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
,?cd=.*?(?:,|$)|ob=
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.Do not forget flag `i`.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/59

or

```
cd=.*?(?:,|$)|[^=,]+=(.*?)(?=,|$)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/57

Answer (score 0):

REgex:

```
(?i)Ob=([^,]+)|(?!.*\bob\b).+
```

Replacement string:

```
$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mN8jJ8/2)

- `(?i)` Will do a case insensitive match.
- `Ob=([^,]+)` Group index 1 contains all the Ob values.
- `|` OR
- `(?!.*\bob\b).+` Match any character one or more times but it won't contain `\bob\b`

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you:

```
^(?!Ob=).*(*SKIP)(*F)|(\w+)=(\w+(?=,|$))
```

You can see that you're getting all keys in group #1 and all values in group #2.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mN8jJ8/5)